# IBM Jazz Team Server: Getting Changes from Changeset using OSLC

Tags: java, rest, changeset, jazz, oslc

I am using the following query to retrieve the Changeset.

OSCL Query:

https://ibm.com:9443/ccm/resource/itemOid/com.ibm.team.scm.ChangeSet/_HFxrmiEbEeS7m-qENunxUw?_mediaType=text/xml

Getting the following response:

```
<scm:ChangeSet itemId="_HFxrmiEbEeS7m-qENunxUw"
properties="">
   <stateId>_W8aNECEbEeS7m-qENunxUw</stateId>
   <immutable>true</immutable>
   <contextId>_Dp6kMdwTEd2jUupDpQV1Rw</contextId>
   <modified>2014-08-11T05:50:11.568Z</modified>
   <mergePredecessor xsi:nil="true" />
   <predecessor>_RaxwgCEbEeS7m-qENunxUw</predecessor>
   <active>false</active>
   <comment>Test</comment>
   <lastUpdatedDate>2014-08-11T05:50:11.225Z</lastUpdatedDate>
   <modifiedBy itemId="_FAv8gA4GEeSsZdvBzERdWQ" />
   <changes>
       <internalId>_HUW6IiEbEeS7m-qENunxUw</internalId>
       <kind>2</kind>
       <before>_nDuHQBhzEeS88s3Rov8pNA</before>
       <after>_HUNJJSEbEeS7m-qENunxUw</after>
       <item itemId="_k5S2oBhzEeSht4FX-gq3Zg" xsi:type="filesystem:FileItemHandle" />
   </changes>
   <component itemId="_RvxoEBhzEeS88s3Rov8pNA" />
   <owner itemId="_FAv8gA4GEeSsZdvBzERdWQ" />
   <xComponentLink xsi:nil="true" />
```

I would like to get the Changes detail. It would be great if someone shares the OSLC 
query to retrieve Changes details.

Answer (score 2):

@user2530633, try the below query, it is not oslc query

> .com/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.filesystem.common.internal.rest.IFilesystemRestService2/changeSetPlus?knownTextContentTypePrefixes=text%2F&knownTextContentTypeStrings=application%2Fxml&knownTextContentTypeStrings=application%2Fjavascript&knownTextContentTypeStrings=application%2Fecmascript&knownTextContentTypeStrings=application%2Fx-javascript&changeSetPath=workspaceId%2F_Dh7kMAHIEeSZzL8CZgHcOQ%2FchangeSetId%2F_quVzDljgEeSiBMylK1kVWg&maxChanges=500"

here just replace your workspaceid and changesetid you can find the changes with the content